# Variable alpha/opacity by specific Y values instead of by color in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am putting up a colorbar tool with Python/Matplotlib and need to change the opacity at arbitrary ranges along the Y axis, instead of having the opacity value associated to the colors themselves.

Reading other posts in SO and various online tutorials, I came across posts showing pcolormesh, facecolor, edgecolor or adding the alpha value as the 4th column in the RGB color definition, but none of them actually solves the problem.

If you run my minimum sample code below (with previous help from SO, which I appreciate), you will see the opacity as defined by each color:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

XMIN        = 0.0
XMAX        = 1.0
YMIN        = 1000.0
YMAX        = 2000.0
RATIO       = 5.0
NUM_COLORS  = 256

color_list      = ([0.2, 0.88, 0.3, 0.25], [0.33, 1.0, 0.25, 0.15], [0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0], [0.0, 0.34, 0.2, 0.1], [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 1.0])  # RGBA, 0 to 1 plus opacity
bounds          = [YMIN, 1100.0, 1400.0, 1800.0, YMAX]
color_tuples    = [(i, color) for i, color in zip(np.interp(bounds, [bounds[0], bounds[-1]], [0, 1]), color_list)]
fig, ax         = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize = (4, 10), num = "Variable opacity by Y?")
segm_cmap       = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Segm_cmap", color_tuples, N = NUM_COLORS)
norm            = plt.Normalize(vmin = bounds[0], vmax = bounds[-1])
img             = ax.imshow(np.linspace(YMIN, YMAX, NUM_COLORS).reshape(-1, 1), cmap = segm_cmap, norm = norm, interpolation = "bilinear",
                        origin = "lower", extent = [XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX])
ax.set_aspect((XMAX - XMIN) / (YMAX - YMIN) * RATIO)

plt.show()
```

However, just like the color boundaries/gradient defined by the "bounds" list, I thought I could make a similar tuple with x,y pairs and the respective opacity and pass it as "alpha" to imshow(), since Matplotlib documentation suggests it accepts, among other things, a 2D array. Something like:

```
opacities = ([[XMIN to XMAX, YMIN to 1200], 1.0], [[XMIN to XMAX, 1200.1 to 1500], 0.5], [[XMIN to XMAX, 1500.1 to YMAX], 0.1])
img = ax.imshow(....., alpha = opacities)
```

That is, a X-range, a Y-range and an opacity value. But I couldn't for the life of me make it work, nor could I find a few sample codes to guide me. So I said, "for justice, I must go to Don Corl...", I mean, I must seek advice from the wise guys if it is at all possible. For your reference, I have Python 3.10.12 and Matplotlib 3.5.1 (Ubuntu 22.04, if relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LinearSegmentedColormap` smooths out the colors (including the alpha values).
When the `alpha=` parameter of `imshow()` is 2D, it needs to have the same number of elements as the image data.  For your use case, `np.where()` can be used to create the alphas from the image data.

The code below ignores the alpha given in the original color list:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

XMIN = 0.0
XMAX = 1.0
RATIO = 5.0
NUM_COLORS = 256

color_list = ([0.2, 0.88, 0.3, 0.25], [0.33, 1.0, 0.25, 0.15], [0.7, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0],
              [0.0, 0.34, 0.2, 0.1], [0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 1.0])  # RGBA, 0 to 1 plus opacity
color_list_rgb = [rgba[:3] for rgba in color_list]
bounds = [1000, 1100, 1400, 1800, 2000]
YMIN = bounds[0]
YMAX = bounds[-1]

color_tuples = [(i, color) for i, color in zip(np.interp(bounds, [bounds[0], bounds[-1]], [0, 1]), color_list_rgb)]

fig, (ax, ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(10, 8))
segm_cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Segm_cmap", color_tuples, N=NUM_COLORS)
norm = plt.Normalize(vmin=bounds[0], vmax=bounds[-1])
img_data = np.linspace(YMIN, YMAX, NUM_COLORS).reshape(-1, 1)
img_alpha = np.where(img_data <= 1200, 1, np.where(img_data <= 1500, 0.5, 0.1))
ax.imshow(img_data, cmap=segm_cmap, norm=norm, interpolation="bilinear",
          origin="lower", extent=[XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX], alpha=img_alpha)
ax.set_aspect((XMAX - XMIN) / (YMAX - YMIN) * RATIO)
ax.set_title('opacity via y')
ax.set_xticks([]) # remove x ticks

ax1.imshow(img_data, cmap=segm_cmap, norm=norm, interpolation="bilinear",
           origin="lower", extent=[XMIN, XMAX, YMIN, YMAX])
ax1.set_aspect((XMAX - XMIN) / (YMAX - YMIN) * RATIO)
ax1.set_title('without opacity')
ax1.set_xticks([])

ax2.hlines(bounds, 0, 1, lw=5, clip_on=False, colors=color_list_rgb)
ax2.set_xlim(XMIN, XMAX)
ax2.set_ylim(YMIN, YMAX)
ax2.set_aspect((XMAX - XMIN) / (YMAX - YMIN) * RATIO)
ax2.set_title('given colors')
for sp in ['top', 'bottom']:
    ax2.spines[sp].set_visible(False)  # hide upper and lower spine
ax2.set_xticks([])

plt.show()
```

[image: 2D alpha in imshow()]